# unable to merge content in NIFI using merge content processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a text file and i need to merge text files into one single file using NIFI 
when I am using merge content processor data is appending unable to merge

example :- if my text file has data like this

in file1:- `2201` 
and in file2:- `2202`
   after using merge content in nifi I am getting output as `22012202`

merge content processor :-[image]

but I need out put as below 
`2201
                           2202
                           2203`
 can any one help me with this i need to do this in nifi only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put Delimiter Strategy as Text and set the Demarcator a new-line by entering shift+enter in the demarcator value.